# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol GetMonitorBrightness referenced in function main

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing a 64 bit console application using Visual studio on a Windows 10 computer, using the Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0

I am trying to get the monitor brightness values using the the GetMonitorBrightness API. The code for the same is as follows:

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

HMONITOR hmonitor;
hmonitor = MonitorFromWindow(GetForegroundWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
DWORD min, curr, max;
if (GetMonitorBrightness(hmonitor,&min,&curr,&max))
{
    cout << ": The error code is  " << GetLastError() << endl;

}
    cout << ": The error code is  " << GetLastError() << endl; 

getchar();
return 0;
```

I am getting the following error:
*LNK2019 unresolved external symbol GetMonitorBrightness referenced in function main*

I have also included the correct header file i.e., highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi.h.

And my monitors are DDC/CI enabled too.

Any idea how I can fix the error for the above mentioned API?

Comment: 1) "_I have also included the correct header file_" Linker doesn't care about header files. Only compiler cares about those. 2) You can fix it, by linking to the correct library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd692939(v=vs.85).aspx), you need to link **Dxva2.lib** to your executable.

You should be able to do it within source file after headers declaration by using pragma like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Dxva2.lib")
```